# Line circle with shadow

Tags: ios, core-graphics, geometry, shadow, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw an empty circle with a stroke color with a shadow.

```
let bezierPath              = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 80, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))

let shapeLayer              = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path             = bezierPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor      = UIColor.white.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth        = 3
shapeLayer.shadowPath       = bezierPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.shadowColor      = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.shadowOffset     = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
shapeLayer.shadowOpacity    = 1

containerView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

[image: The result]

But shadow is filling the entire circle. How to remove it and keep the outer shadow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just omit setting `shapeLayer.shadowPath` and you will get something like this (the layer's standard shadow, which is basically the opaque parts of the layer):

[image]